# GNU Parallel produces different output compared to while loop with this sed command

Tags: bash, sed, while-loop, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

I'm confused about how GNU Parallel is handling piped input fed into a sed inplace file edit, and I'd like understand what it's doing (and also so that I can get it to work!).

I have two files, f1 and f2 that look as follows:

**f1**

```
a11    a12    a13
a21    a22    a23
...
an1    an2    an3
```

**f2**

```
a41
stuff
...
a91
stuff
...
```

and what I'm trying to do is concatenate elements in the second and third columns from **f1** to each corresponding element (of the first column) present in **f2**, such that **f2** looks like:

```
a41 a42 a43
stuff
...
a91 a92 a93
things
...
```

A simple while loop does the job:

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -r e1 e2 e3; do sed -i "s/$e1/& $e2 $e3/g" f2 ; done < f1
```

And I tried to replicate this using GNU Parallel like so:

```
cat f1 | parallel --colsep '\t' -q sed -i "s/{1}/& {2} {3}/g" f2
```

which modifies only a fraction of the entries in **f2** compared to the while loop. It would look something like this:

```
a41 a42 a43
stuff
...
a91
things
...
a71 a72 a73
words
...
```

So, any ideas about what's happening, and how I can replicate the while loop behaviour using GNU Parallel?

Thanks!

Comment: You want multiple parallel `sed`s modifying a single file in place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is due to sed not replacing in place. What it does is to create a new file which is then moved to the original file.

So what you are seeing is multiple `sed`s in parallel each creating a new file. When one of these finishes, it will overwrite the original, but this will no be seen by the other `sed`s currently running that will still be working on the original file.

So if you use `-j1` you will not see this problem. But you will also not see a speed up.

I am not sure GNU Parallel can help you here. A solution is to convert f2 into a big sed script.

Comment: Thanks for your insight. It seems like my approach isn't a good way to handle this task.

Answer (score 1):

idk about all that parallel stuff but if you're just trying to do something more efficient than a sed script called from a shell loop then all you need is:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next} {print ($1 in a ? a[$1] : $0)}' f1 f2
```

You can use -i inplace with GNU awk if you feel that's better than just using an explicit tmp file.

Comment: This is a beautiful awk one-liner. Pretty damn fast runtime for the files I'm playing with. Thanks for the solution. I understand that, in principle, the one-liner doesn't go through all the needless sed loops. But, could you explain what makes this awk command so fast?

Comment: The shell was designed to be (and therefore is optimized to be) an environment from which to call UNIX tools, NOT a tool to manipulate text. awk was designed to be (and therefore is optimized to be) the UNIX tool to manipulate text. It's just a case of using the right tool for each job.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a variant of Ed Morton's answer.  This variant illustrates a very useful technique and should be (very slightly) faster as it avoids checking NR==NFR:

`awk -v dict=f1 'BEGIN { while (getline < dict) {a[$1]=$0} } {print ($1 in a ? a[$1] : $0)}' f2`